# I tried using ScrollView in a fragment, but it doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a question about my Android App. I have a menu with different options. For the home button, I use a fragment, in which I want to scroll. First time, I added ScrollView in the fragment xml, but it didn't work at all. Then, I tried ScrollView in the main activity with the menu, but it didn't work.

Here is the main activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomAppBar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green_700"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="10dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/light_grey"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/light_grey"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@font/josefin_sans_semibold"
            android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onPressFab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is the fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/green_700"
        app:cardElevation="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.428"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MaterialCardView.Cut">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/search_outline"
                android:fontFamily="@font/josefin_sans_semibold"
                android:hint="Search Barcode"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_200"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.183"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sbutton"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_transparent"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="208dp"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome back!"
        android:textColor="@color/darker_grey"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout">

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would be greatful if you have any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Also, remember that the contents must be able to overflow the screen for the scrollview to be able to scroll, otherwise it would behave like any normal layout.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your use case correctly but if you want your fragment to be scrollable then use scrollview inside your fragment layout and make sure `android:isScrollContainer` is set to true.